# How to report events in real time with Debezium Sql Server Connector for Apache Camel?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, apache-camel, debezium

I am trying to replicate changes from one database to another, using [Debezium Sql Server Connector for Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/debezium-sqlserver-component.html) via the following Spring Boot starters:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-debezium-sqlserver-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So far, I am just logging the events generated to a specific table:

```
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("debezium-sqlserver:iwd" +
                "?databaseHostname=localhost" +
                "&databasePort=1433" +
                "&databaseServerName=iwd" +
                "&databaseDbname=iwd" +
                "&databaseUser=sa" +
                "&databasePassword=MyPassword-1" +
                "&tableWhitelist=dbo.MyTable-1" +
                "&offsetStorageFileName=./offset-file-1.dat" +
                "&databaseHistoryFileFilename=./history-file-1.dat")
        .routeId(MyRoute.class.getName() + ".DatabaseReader")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Incoming message ${body} with headers ${headers}");
    }
}
```

When initializing the application it reports an event for each row of the table, the problem is that later it does not report the events in real time, for example if I insert or update a row in the table.

Comment: Hi, please make sure you followed https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/connectors/sqlserver.html#setting-up-sqlserver and you have SQL Server Agent running

Comment: Thanks @JiriPechanec. In fact, I only had CDC enabled at the database level, [enabling CDC for each table that I plan to monitor](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/connectors/sqlserver.html#setting-up-sqlserver) and running SQL Server Agent, as you suggested, solved the problem. (_Please, if you wish, publish it as a more complete answer and I will accept it_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/connectors/sqlserver.html#setting-up-sqlserver and make sure that:

- CDC is enabled for database

  ```
  USE MyDB
  GO
  EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db
  GO
  ```
- CDC is enabled for tables you want to capture

  ```
  EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
  @source_schema = N'dbo',
  @source_name   = N'MyTable',
  @role_name     = N'MyRole',
  GO
  ```
- SQL Server Agent is running
- Debezium user has privileges to read source and change tables